# Change Velocity templates based on User-Agent

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, velocity

I have looked everywhere for solutions, but it seems the technology is not so popular anymore so there don't seem to be any answers either.

It seems I am up against the seemingly impossible task of serving different Apache Velocity templates (*.vm* files) based on *User-Agent*.

The problem arised on a legacy web project from the need to serve mobile users a little differently. The version for velocity is 1.6.2 and for velocity-tools 2.0.

I have a lot of freedom with respect to how to do it, except that I would like the User-Agent checking to be on the server-side before rendering the Velocity files.

**tl;dr**

How to render different *.vm* files based on some algorithmic criteria (i.e. User-Agent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked was creating in *web.xml* an additional `VelocityLayoutServlet` with a separate `<param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>` and with a different `<url-pattern>` for the velocity files.

To complete the solution,

`request.getRequestDispatcher(
   getPath(request.getHeader("User-Agent"))
).forward(request, response);`

where `getPath(String userAgent)` returns the correct **.vm* path based on *User-Agent* (for which the [Mobile ESP library](https://github.com/ahand/mobileesp) was used).

Caveat:
Unfortunately, the `<url-pattern>` does not support simultaneously a folder path expression and a file extension expression, but the former did the job and as such `<url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>` became `<url-pattern>velocity/*</url-pattern>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add user agent to template

```
  String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
  mapForTemplate.put("userAgent", userAgent);
```

Then add your logic in template

```
 #if ($userAgent == "....")
   #include( "chrome.vm" )
 #else
    #include( "firefox.vm" )
 #end
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it completely on the server side? Somehow specifying that for User-Agent *x* I am serving `vm1/*.vm` and for User-Agent *y* I am serving `vm2/*.vm`?

Comment: Why not? Add if "...".equals(userAgent ) template ="vm1/....vm" else template ="vm2/....vm"

Comment: Unfortunately, the legacy project is setup in such a way that *VelocityLayoutServlet* is the defined servlet in the web.xml with its corresponding *velocity.properties* where the included *.vm* file paths are included. I cannot see any way to specify templates at any point in the setup.